# Make username unique and save it on the Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an android app(Android Studio) that requires users to sign up/ login to be able to access it. I'm using firebase to store registered users. Currently the Sign Up form take the user's email, password and name and the login requires only the email and password. Here is my register activity:

```
 private void createUserAccount(final String email, final String name, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
               if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   showMessage("Account Created");
                   updateUserInfo(name, pickedImgUri,mAuth.getCurrentUser());
               }
               else{
                   showMessage("account_activity creation failed" + task.getException().getMessage());
                   regBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }
            }
        });

    }
           private void updateUserInfo(final String name, Uri pickedImgUri, final FirebaseUser currentUser) {
            StorageReference mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("user_photos");
            final StorageReference imageFilePath = mStorage.child(pickedImgUri.getLastPathSegment());
            imageFilePath.putFile(pickedImgUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    imageFilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(name)
                                    .setPhotoUri(uri)
                                    .build();

                            currentUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                showMessage("Register complete");
                                                UpdateUI();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

    }
```

How can I add a username field and make it unique for every user? and is it possible to make all the users information appear on the Firebase Database rather than under Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create profile fields on the the `auth` user beyond what's already there.

For username, you're best off creating a `users` collection in firestore. Each entry can be keyed by the user's UID assigned from `auth`. When you create the entry, create it with a `username` field. Then, before any new users lock in their username, you can run a query against firestore with a `where('username', '==', $username)` where `$username` is the name the user is attempting to reserve. If the record exists, the username is taken and the user will have to choose something else.

Here's a YouTube tutorial on using `auth` and `firestore` together for use cases like yours: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWy9ylc3f9U